# Set windows clock format to Y-m-d H:i:s in status bar on small icon mode

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, clock

Is it possible to set the status bar clock format to `Y-m-d H:i:s` (PHP format) in small icon mode? E.g. `2010-07-05 06:19:22`

Current format:

[image: It's the current format]

Full sized icon mode (note the lack of seconds):

[image: It's full sized icon mode]

I don't want to use third party apps so if it's not possible, please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of the clock in Windows 7 is determined by the amount of space available.  Even in small icon mode, if you make the taskbar taller, it should then display the date.

If there isn't sufficient vertical space, Windows 7 will automatically remove the date string.  I don't believe that it's possible to change that behavior.