# How can I customize the Windows 7 clock to show full date/time?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area, clock

I'm currently using Windows 7 Ultimate. I've seen that some people have full date/time info in their system tray clock like this:

[image: full date/time information in system tray clock]

However, my current system tray clock is shown like this:

[image]

I wonder how I could change the clock, but can't find any way to do so *without a third party application*. Maybe there's a way to hack into registry or something?

I know that I can [enlarge the taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/160069/set-Windows-clock-format-to-y-m-d-his-in-status-bar-on-small-icon-mode) to get it, but I don't want to lose my screen space that way.

---

**solved**:
Finally I gave up with the "non 3rd party" idea and use [Tclock Light](http://homepage1.nifty.com/kazubon/tclocklight/) to do it, this small free, portable application do it awesome :D.
[image: finally I use tclock]

Comment: Are you sure these "some people" aren't using third party tools?

Comment: Could be that theme.  Aero taskbar shows date and time.

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg, 
maybe I'll some in [Krazy_Kaos](http://superuser.com/questions/91242/adding-date-and-time-to-systems-tray-in-Windows-7) suggest

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link.  It sounds like what you are looking for.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9235/change-display-under-the-system-tray-clock-in-windows-7/

Comment: thanks, but I've tried that link before,
in that, they just show how to customize the way Win7 display date, and we must use Large Icon to get Win7 display date first.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.